# ERROR/MainProcess consumer: Cannot connect to amqp:// (Docker Compose and Celery-RabbitMQ)

Tags: rabbitmq, celery, docker-compose

I'm trying to make Flask, Celery and RabbitMQ work using docker-compose service. I am able to get the things up and running, but the Celery client isn't able to connect to the RabbitMQ server. On the celery server start, I get this message:

```
    [2017-02-27 17:52:17,466: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot  connect to amqp://radmin:**@174.138.76.93:5672//: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer.
    Trying again in 2.00 seconds...

    [2017-02-27 17:52:19,481: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to  amqp://radmin:**@174.138.76.93:5672//: Socket closed.
    Trying again in 4.00 seconds...
```

My folder structure for the project is:

```
    ├── docker-compose.yml
    ├── order
    │   ├── Dockerfile
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __init__.pyc
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   └── __init__.cpython-35.pyc
    │   ├── requirements.txt
    │   ├── main.py
    ├── celery
    │   ├── Dockerfile
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── requirements.txt
    │   └── tasks.py
    ├── proxy
    │   ├── Dockerfile
    │   └── order.conf
```

The order folder is where the main flask server is and the celery has the folder where my celery tasks are present. I'm creating a separate celery worker, wherein the tasks submitted by main.py through

```
    task = celery.send_task('mytasks.outputservice', args=[arg1, arg2])
```

would be received by tasks.py `@app.task(name='mytasks.outputservice')`

I've implemented this locally and it works fine (the remote celery tasks thing), I guess the issue is with the RabbitMQ and Celery connections.

My docker-compose file is:

```
    version: '2.1'

    services:

    # Application
       ordermanagement:
          restart: always
          build: ./ordermanagement
          expose:
           - "8080"
          ports:
           - "8080:8080"
          volumes:
           - /usr/src/app/static
          depends_on:
           - rabbit
           - worker
         #env_file: .env
         #command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn -w 2 --timeout 90 --keep-        alive 90 --bind :8080 scheduledpurchases:app

     # RabbitMQ
     rabbit:
       hostname: rabbit
       image: rabbitmq:management
       environment:
         - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=radmin
         - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=radmin
       ports:
         - "5672:5672"  # we forward this port because it's useful for debugging
         - "15672:15672"  # here, we can access rabbitmq management plugin

       # Nginx server
       proxy:
         restart: always
         build: ./proxy
         expose:
           - "80"
         ports:
           - "85:80"
         depends_on:
           - ordermanagement
         links:
           - ordermanagement:ordermanagement

        # Celery worker
         worker:
           build: ./ordermanagement_celery
           user: nobody
           depends_on:
             - rabbit
```

I've seen other questions related to Celery and RabbitMQ, but majority of the problems were either resolved (ip address resolution) or some other small issue.

If someone could give me lead on how to resolve this.

PS: I'm directly deploying to DigitalOcean servers from terminal, checked the ip for RabbitMQ (Celery Broker URL, it is the same as the docker-machine ip).

Comment: I got the same error, the I solved it by creating a new user along with assigning all the permissions to him